# Magento 2: Verify email address with Third-party API

Tags: magento2.3.4

I have to validate the email address before adding into the website for the below areas. Verification will be by some API like
https://www.zerobounce.net/docs/email-validation-api-quickstart/

1. Register
2. Newsletter subscribe
3. Checkout

Also, need to get from where this email address is added, for example, Registration form, Checkout, Newsletter form, etc

Please give me some suggestions regarding this.

Comment: You can took reference form `/V1/customers/isEmailAvailable` and `/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php`

Comment: /vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php

For which thing?

Comment: Isemailavailable function is written in this file

Comment: For checkout and registration, I need to check the Email. If valid then allow to register and checkout and save the API data at last if it's a valid email. Can you please help?